# Is it possible to create a vignette mask in photoshop for compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a project that I have been working on for a while that I end up bringing in to photoshop for a custom vignette. Since I keep going back and forth, I would love to just use the mask from photoshop and combine it into the compositor for the final output.

I think I have it part way figured out but don't see a mapping node to make the image fit to the right size in the final composite.

It is too big! Can it be controlled?
[image]

Comment: try using Add > Distort > Scale and choose which is desired (probably Render size). Also maybe - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51890/how-to-scale-the-rendered-image-in-composition

Comment: That did the trick for scaling. Thank you. But... the control of the shadows goes to heck, so I think I will stay with the photoshop route for now. Much more control!

Comment: I often was doing vignette with compositing and usually it should work, not sure what was with shadows in your project. In general, ColorRamp node is just for that purpose, so feeding image to be multipled over the render for the node is a way to go.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr Zak. It felt like the shadows blocked up really fast. Could be my mask or it could be the low res test render (it's a five hour render for the final due to noise and fireflies).  I will have to try it again when I can get back to the studio. Today, the snow storm means surfing the interwebs for new blender techniques! ;-)